# Тире нужно или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

В "Двенадцатой ночи" гармония восстанавливается, а в "Гамлете" рушится.

Перед словом "рушится" нужно тире?

Answer (score 2):

**Авторский выбор, постановка тире зависит от контекста, интонация вариантов разная.**

**1) Параллельная интонация, названия выделены логическим ударением:**

В "ДвенАдцатой ночи" //гармония восстанавливается, а в "ГАмлете" ― рушится.

**2) Нет параллельной интонации, подчеркнуто противопоставление "восстанавливается - рушится":**

В "Двенадцатой ночи" гармония восстанАвливается, а в "Гамлете" рУшится.

Comment: Против второго варианта говорит то обстоятельство, что "гармония" не одна и та же: вторая пьеса не является продолжением первой, в ней своя "гармония".

Comment: По-моему, нет разницы. Здесь сравниваются две пьесы, и в предложении мы можем логически выделить пары слов: В "ДвенАдцатой ночи "-  в "ГАмлете" или  восстанавливается - рушится. Знаете, Alex_ander, мне всегда кажется, что вы ждете от грамматики слишком много, а ведь это формальная наука (наука формы), которая не может передать очень тонкие смысловые различия. Такие различия "прочитываются" при осознании всего текста, а не отдельных грамматических форм.

Comment: А равзе тут нет обязательного правила постановки тире по той причине, что вторая часть предложения неполная?

Comment: В неполных предложениях допускаются оба варианта. При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93